# Wagtail CMS вложенный StreamBlock

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте.

Изучаю [Wagtail CMS](http://wagtail.io/) для Django, и мне очень понравилась концепция StreamBlock.

Интересует следующее: каким образом сделать вложенным StreamBlock, пусть и обходными путями?

Есть блок такого типа:

```
<section class="section bg-light" id="features">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h3 class="title">{{ self.title }}</h3>
                <p class="text-muted sub-title">{{ self.sub }}</p>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="row">

            {% for item in features_item %}
                {% include 'sections/features_item_block.html' %}
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </div> 
    </div> 
</section>
```

Внутрь которого я хочу наследовать n количество других блоков такого типа:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="features-box">
        <i class="pe-7s-{{ item.icon }}"></i>
        <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">{{ item.sub }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Понятно, что в последствии, когда это будет реализовано, будет меняться `col-sm` чтобы блоки грамотно центрировались, но на данном этапе интересно другое.

```
class FeaturesItemBlock(StructBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)
    sub = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)
    icon = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)

class FeaturesBlock(StructBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)
    sub = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)
    features_item = FeaturesItemBlock()

    class Meta:
        icon = 'features'
        template = "sections/features_block.html"

class SectionsStreamBlock(StreamBlock):
    features_item_block = FeaturesBlock()
```

Сейчас это выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть при выборке блока, он сразу же добавляется с дочерним `FeaturesItemBlock`, но а в идеале, чтобы был плюсик для добавления этого блока.

Если кто-то решал подобную задачу, будут очень признателен за ответ либо ссылку.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь за преждевременный вопрос.
Всё оказалось куда проще, чем я думал.

Решается при помощи `ListBlock`, а именно:

```
class FeaturesBlock(StructBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)
    sub = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)
    features_item = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.StructBlock([
    ('title', blocks.CharBlock(required=True)),
    ('sub', blocks.CharBlock()),
    ('icon', blocks.CharBlock())
]))

    class Meta:
        icon = 'features'
        template = "sections/features_block.html"
```

И `FeaturesItemBlock` не нужен вовсе.